# Concatenate string && integer as array variable of double type - MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, concatenation, string-concatenation

I currently look for an advice on the below piece of code which consists of *efficiently* looping through a dataset (*of cell type*) and extracting each column as data vector.

```
[i,j]=size(fimat);
k=2;
while k<=j % looping through columns
[num2str(k-1),'yr']=cell2mat(fimat(:,k)); %extract each column as vector
k=k+1;
end
```

My matter undeniably lies in the following statement:

```
[num2str(k-1),'yr']
```

that correctly concatenates numbers (*reflected by variable k*) and string name '*yr*'. However the syntax fails in assigning for instance *(during 1st iteration)*

```
1yr=cell2mat(fimat(:,2))
```

The resulting error *speaks from itself*

```
Error: An array for multiple LHS assignment cannot contain LEX_TS_STRING.
```

but I'm still figuring out a way to do it. Thus any feedback would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Here is my **answer** to the question*, for sharing purposes. Hope it will help and Thanks to the contributors of this post.

```
[i,j]=size(fimat); %get dimension of dataset (of cell type)
numdata=cell2mat(fimat(1:i,2:j)); %extract only numeric from dataset
for k=1:j-1
eval(sprintf('yr%d = numdata(:,k)', k));
end
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, in matlab, a variable name cannot start with a digit. You should modify your code such that the variable name starts with either a letter or an underscore.

For instance `['yr' num2str(k-1)]` or `['_' num2str(k-1) 'yr']` would be better.

Then, what you are trying to do is very strongly discouraged by everyone, including [The Mathworks](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html). It would be much better to use a cell `yr` and call to `yr{k}` rather than iterative variable names:

```
yr = cell(j,1);
for k = 2:j
    yr{k-1} = cell2mat(fimat(:,k));
end
```

Anyway, if you still want to do this, you can use [`eval`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html)

```
while k<=j
    eval(['_' num2str(k-1) 'yr = cell2mat(fimat(:,k));']);
    k=k+1;
end
```

Best,

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, although it does not empirically resolve the stated `Error: An array for multiple LHS assignment cannot contain LEX_TS_STRING`.

Comment: Neither of the suggestion seems to work. In addition i've a bit amended your syntax. 1/ using `eval`: `while k<=j
    eval(['_' num2str(k-1) 'yr']) = cell2mat(fimat(:,k));
    k=k+1;
end` . 2/ using `for loop`: `[i,j]=size(fimat);
yr = cell(1,j);
for k = 2:j
    yr{k-1} = cell2mat(fimat(:,k));
    
end` . I keep working on it but Thanks for the ideas which drive me close to the solution.

Comment: What do you mean by "not seem to work" ? Do you have an error message ?

Comment: by "not seem to work" I'd nicely like to say "does not work" by thanking you for your assistance. 1/ `eval` Error from your post (_stricto sensu_)= `Error: The input character is not valid in MATLAB statements or expressions`. From mine (_as slightly amended_):`In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same.` Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You can not dynamically create variable names like you did. The left side of the `=` must be a identifier, not a char. The alternative I recommend is to use a cell array instead of individual variable names. For example:

```
yr{k-1}=cell2mat(fimat(:,k))
```

If you must use variable names with numbers, which I strongly recommend not to do, you have to use `eval` for the line. Alternatives which I strongly recommend to check before using `eval` are `struct` with dynamic field names and `containers.Map`

Comment: the 2 matters with `yr{k-1}=cell2mat(fimat(:,k))` although the idea looks acceptable in theory: 1/ `yr` is of cell type rather than variables of double type. Corollary it's empty as it can't be fed with `cell2mat(fimat(:,k))` which is of double type. I've tried `cell2mat(yr{k-1})=cell2mat(fimat(:,k))` as way around to ensure type uniqueness but this ends up with dimension issues. Also there are no further improvements with `cell2mat(i,yr{k-1})=cell2mat(fimat(:,k))` as a trial. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You have to use `yr{k-1}` instead of `yr`, that's your double.

Comment: it was done and repeated but still as explained previously, unfortunately.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve with the `cell2mat` on the left side of the assignment.

Comment: `cell2mat` merely converts to `double` the columns from `fimat` (_dataset of cell type_) which are stored to vectors (_of double type_) named `yr1, yr2....yrk`.

Comment: I understand that use of `cell2mat`, on the right side of the "=". But I don't understand the use on the left side of the "=".

Comment: It was just a guess: a _desparate_ trial to make `yr` as of `double` type in an attempt to fill it  with `cell2mat` on the right and side

Comment: As I wrote, I understand the use of `cell2mat` on the right side, bot not on the left side of the assignment. If you still have this problem, I recommend to rephrase your question and explain what output data you want.

Comment: For sharing purposes,  please see below the piece of codes as I eventually worked out the solution yesterday which detailed my expectations. I am grateful to your contributions on this post. Cheers.